# Error Unhandled Exception: setState() called after dispose() when switch another BottomNavigationBar

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a 5 menu in `BottomNavigationBar` . When I switch from one to another, sometimes I got an error message like

```
E/flutter (13314): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: setState() called after dispose(): _PromoProductState#a00c8(lifecycle state: defunct, not mounted)
E/flutter (13314): This error happens if you call setState() on a State object for a widget that no longer appears in the widget tree (e.g., whose parent widget no longer includes the widget in its build). This error can occur when code calls setState() from a timer or an animation callback.
E/flutter (13314): The preferred solution is to cancel the timer or stop listening to the animation in the dispose() callback. Another solution is to check the "mounted" property of this object before calling setState() to ensure the object is still in the tree.
E/flutter (13314): This error might indicate a memory leak if setState() is being called because another object is retaining a reference to this State object after it has been removed from the tree. To avoid memory leaks, consider breaking the reference to this object during dispose().
E/flutter (13314): #0      State.setState.<anonymous closure> 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:1112
E/flutter (13314): #1      State.setState 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:1147
E/flutter (13314): #2      _PromoProductState.initState.<anonymous closure> 
package:tokopedia/widgets/promo_product.dart:16
E/flutter (13314): #3      _rootRun  (dart:async/zone.dart:1122:38)
E/flutter (13314): #4      _CustomZone.run  (dart:async/zone.dart:1023:19)
E/flutter (13314): #5      _CustomZone.runGuarded  (dart:async/zone.dart:925:7)
E/flutter (13314): #6      _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure>  (dart:async/zone.dart:965:23)
E/flutter (13314): #7      _rootRun  (dart:async/zone.dart:1126:13)
E/flutter (13314): #8      _CustomZone.run  (dart:async/zone.dart:1023:19)
E/flutter (13314): #9      _CustomZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure>  (dart:async/zone.dart:949:23)
E/flutter (13314): #10     Timer._createTimer.<anonymous closure>  (dart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart:23:15)
E/flutter (13314): #11     _Timer._runTimers  (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:384:19)
E/flutter (13314): #12     _Timer._handleMessage  (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:418:5)
E/flutter (13314): #13     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage  (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:174:12)
```

This only happens if I move (fast) from another menu to the `home menu` which contains static data (doesn't call api for now).

I think maybe this code the problem

```
@override
void initState() {
  Provider.of<LoadingState>(context, listen: false).setLoading = 0;
  Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
    setState(() {
      time = time.add(Duration(seconds: -1));
    });
  });
  super.initState();
  listBottomWidget.add(HomeTab());
  listBottomWidget.add(FeedTab());
  listBottomWidget.add(InboxTab());
  listBottomWidget.add(CartTab());
  listBottomWidget.add(AccountTab());
}
```

But I don't know for sure

The error message only show when I switch to `HomeTab()`.

Here is my home.dart

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:badges/badges.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:tokopedia/providers/loading_state.dart';
import 'package:tokopedia/view/tabs/tab_account.dart';
import 'package:tokopedia/view/tabs/tab_cart.dart';
import 'package:tokopedia/view/tabs/tab_feed.dart';
import 'package:tokopedia/view/tabs/tab_home.dart';
import 'package:tokopedia/view/tabs/tab_inbox.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => HomePageState();
}

class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  DateTime time = DateTime.now();
  int selectedPosition = 0;
  List<Widget> listBottomWidget = new List();

  @override
  void initState() {
    Provider.of<LoadingState>(context, listen: false).setLoading = 0;
    Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      setState(() {
        time = time.add(Duration(seconds: -1));
      });
    });
    super.initState();
    listBottomWidget.add(HomeTab());
    listBottomWidget.add(FeedTab());
    listBottomWidget.add(InboxTab());
    listBottomWidget.add(CartTab());
    listBottomWidget.add(AccountTab());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        title: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 12.0),
              child: Image.asset(
                "assets/images/qrcode.png",
                width: 30,
                height: 30,
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.grey[100],
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                    Radius.circular(5.0),
                  ),
                ),
                child: TextField(
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    prefixIcon: Icon(
                      Icons.search,
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    ),
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                    hintText: 'What you need?',
                  ),
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          BadgeIconButton(
            itemCount: 0,
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.favorite,
              size: 28.0,
              color: Colors.grey[400],
            ),
            badgeColor: Colors.red,
            badgeTextColor: Colors.white,
            hideZeroCount: true,
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
          BadgeIconButton(
            itemCount: 4,
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.notifications,
              size: 28.0,
              color: Colors.grey[400],
            ),
            badgeColor: Colors.red,
            badgeTextColor: Colors.white,
            hideZeroCount: true,
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Builder(
        builder: (context) {
          return listBottomWidget[selectedPosition];
        },
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        currentIndex: selectedPosition, // this will be set when a tab is tapped
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            title: Text('Home'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.book),
            title: Text('Feed'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.mail),
            title: Text('Inbox'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
            title: Text('Cart'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.people),
            title: Text('Account'),
          ),
        ],
        onTap: (position) {
          setState(() {
            selectedPosition = position;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Am I miss something?

Thanks

**Edited**

My homeTab

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:tokopedia/widgets/banner_belanja_untung.dart';
import 'package:tokopedia/widgets/banner_beli_kebutuhan.dart';
import 'package:tokopedia/widgets/banner_promo_special.dart';
import 'package:tokopedia/widgets/image_slider.dart';
import 'package:tokopedia/widgets/kategori_pilihan.dart';
import 'package:tokopedia/widgets/menu_item.dart';
import 'package:tokopedia/widgets/most_trending_product.dart';
import 'package:tokopedia/widgets/promo_product.dart';

class HomeTab extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeTabState createState() => _HomeTabState();
}

class _HomeTabState extends State<HomeTab> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var greyArea = Container(
      height: 10.0,
      color: Colors.grey[200],
    );
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          ImageSliderWidget(),
          MenuItemWidget(),
          greyArea,
          PromoProduct(),
          greyArea,
          BannerPromoSpecial(),
          KategoriPilihan(),
          greyArea,
          BannerBelanjaUntung(),
          greyArea,
          MostTrendingProduct(),
          greyArea,
          BannerBeliKebutuhan(),
          greyArea,
          KategoriPilihan(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Inside my `PromoProduct` widget

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PromoProduct extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PromoProductState createState() => _PromoProductState();
}

class _PromoProductState extends State<PromoProduct> {
  DateTime time = DateTime.now();

  @override
  void initState() {
    Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      setState(() {
        time = time.add(Duration(seconds: -1));
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var promoProductItems = [
      {
        "image": "assets/images/product/tas.jpg",
        "real_price": "Rp 249.000",
        "discount_price": "Rp 87.150",
        "discount_percent": "65",
      },
      {
        "image": "assets/images/product/qtela.jpg",
        "real_price": "Rp 25.000",
        "discount_price": "Rp 20.000",
        "discount_percent": "20",
      },
      {
        "image": "assets/images/product/tropicana_slim.jpg",
        "real_price": "Rp 83.500",
        "discount_price": "Rp 58.500",
        "discount_percent": "30",
      },
      {
        "image": "assets/images/product/pipo_frixion.jpg",
        "real_price": "Rp 27.000",
        "discount_price": "Rp 16.200",
        "discount_percent": "40",
      },
      {
        "image": "assets/images/product/bioderma_sebium.jpg",
        "real_price": "Rp 252.625",
        "discount_price": "Rp 155.000",
        "discount_percent": "39",
      },
      {
        "image": "assets/images/product/maxim_new_prestige.jpg",
        "real_price": "Rp 612.000",
        "discount_price": "Rp 263.000",
        "discount_percent": "57",
      },
    ];
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text("Flash Sale   ",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        )),
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Color(0xffff3e2f),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(6.0)),
                      ),
                      child: Text(
                        time.hour.toString().padLeft(2, "0"),
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      " : ",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xffff3e2f),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Color(0xffff3e2f),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(6.0)),
                      ),
                      child: Text(
                        time.minute.toString().padLeft(2, "0"),
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      " : ",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xffff3e2f),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Color(0xffff3e2f),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(6.0)),
                      ),
                      child: Text(
                        time.second.toString().padLeft(2, "0"),
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Text("Lihat Semuanya",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.green,
                  )),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: 280.0,
          child: IgnorePointer(
            child: GridView.count(
              crossAxisCount: 3,
              children: List.generate(
                promoProductItems.length,
                (index) {
                  return Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Stack(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            height: 85.0,
                            child: Image.asset(
                              promoProductItems[index]["image"],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Positioned(
                            top: 0,
                            right: 0,
                            child: Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                              child: Text(
                                "${promoProductItems[index]["discount_percent"]} OFF",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.red[900],
                                  fontSize: 10.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                ),
                              ),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.red[100],
                                border: Border.all(
                                  color: Colors.red,
                                  width: 2.0,
                                ),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                  Radius.circular(12.0),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Text(
                        promoProductItems[index]["real_price"],
                        style: TextStyle(
                          decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        promoProductItems[index]["discount_price"],
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.orange[900],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not a completely right way, but sometimes you will need to use it. Like your issue. Define a bool and change it when the widget disposed. And don't use any `setState` without it. For example;

```
DateTime time = DateTime.now();
bool _disposed = false;

@override
void initState() {
  Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
    if (!_disposed)
      setState(() {
        time = time.add(Duration(seconds: -1));
      });
  });
  super.initState();
}

@override
void dispose() {
  _disposed = true;
  super.dispose();
}
```

Comment: Ok I will try your code and give your feedback. Thanks bro

Comment: Should I `always` use `void dispose()` when I use setState? Sorry for new in flutter

Comment: You're most welcome! Use it when you want to be sure that `setState` is not triggered after dispose.

Comment: `Dispose` mean I switch the page to another page right?

Comment: dispose mean that your widget not appear on the screen anymore. For more detail check the life cycle of widget in flutter; https://www.developerlibs.com/2019/12/flutter-lifecycle-widgets.html

Comment: Ah got it. Thanks bro for your advice

Answer (score 1):

In the one of your tabs you are using some codes triggered `setState` method. Probably in a future function. Please share inside the tab that you get this error when you leave it.

Comment: Hi @malibayram91 Yes inside one of my widget. Check my update code in `Edited`